# Serialize values in T-SQL query

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, serialization

I'm trying to fill tables in a database with values from a file.
I got all that working but I got a problem.
The application using the database (C# application) is serializing the data values when inserting data and then de-serializing them when they are later used.

I don't have access to the code to the C# application so don't have much info about it.
In the table there is two fields, one for friendlyValue and one for value

For example:

"71" -> "214783719"

"Kultur, Montessori  Reggio Emilia -> |S3VsdHVyLCBNb250ZXNzb3Jp|UmVnZ2lvIEVtaWxpYQ==|"

"0 (F, förskoleklass)  1  2  3  4  5"  -> "|MCAoRiwgZsO2cnNrb2xla2xhc3Mp|MQ==|Mg==|Mw==|NA==|NQ==|"

"Språk" -> "|U3Byw6Vr|"

"15-55" - > "21474836632147483703"

Is there anyway to serialize the data in this manner in a T-SQL query? 
With a stored procedure or function?

Comment: No way it's seems to serialize & deserialization. It might be some Encryption & decryption...

Comment: Looks like base64 encoded.

Comment: Ah, you're right. The text seems to be base64 encoded.
What about the numbers though?

Comment: The numbers 15,55,71 all seem to be offset by `2147483648` for some reason.

Comment: SO helped you to decipher the serializer of your application

Comment: Thanks for the comments, helped me to get further.

Comment: I just read this thread and thought it was an interesting predicament. What did you end up doing? Have you tried using XQuery to encode the data? It doesn't look like this generates _exactly_ the same thing, but maybe it could be a place to start: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10002d/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to binaries of the C# application? If so, you can use a .NET decompiler software like `ILSpy` which you can download from [here](http://ilspy.net/) to decompile .NET binaries and see how your data is encoded.